# Bittorrent extended message

Tags: bittorrent

I cannot find documentation anywhere that will tell me what this message means.

it looks like this in Wireshark.

00 00 00 03 14 03 01

I realize it is a 3 byte message, it is an extended message, ie type 20, but I don't know what 03 01 represent.

The scenario is that I send an 'Interested' message to the peer to unchoke my client, the peer then responds with the above message, followed by the 'Unchoke' message.

Answer (score 1):

It is a *extension message* with **ID = 3** and **01** is message data.
What **ID = 3** means in this case, is defined by the previously *extended message handshake* (**ID = 0**) your client has sent.

A educated guess is that the message you see means: **upload_only = 1**. (['Extension for Partial Seeds' - BEP21](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101150035/http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0021.html))

---

**Addendum:**
uTorrent and most other clients implementation of *upload_only* differs from the 'out of date' [specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101150035/http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0021.html) explained [here; <sub>alus = Greg Hazel</sub>](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/45946-clarification-of-partial-seeds/?do=findComment&comment=280236)
It's defined as a *extension message* in the *extension handshake* were the 1 byte message data means: **0x00 = false** or **< anything else> = true**. 
This can be verified by using Wireshark.

Comment: upload_only is not a message, it's only part of the extension handshake

Comment: I have used Wireshark with a 'real' client and I have seen that message before but I can't tell from Wireshark what is done specifically for that message.  ie I haven't seen that message sent by itself to a peer and a response to that message.

Comment: @Ray_Write There is no required response to that message, but if both clients sends **upload_only=1**, they will immediately disconnect from each other, as then they both either are full- or partial- seeds and don't want to download anything.

Comment: I believe @the8472 is correct, upload_only is not a message, it's part of the extended message (message type 20) which is part of the handshake.