# What does upload_only=3 mean in extended BitTorrent handshake

Tags: p2p, bittorrent

I need help to understand what does `upload_only=3` mean in extended BitTorrent handshake.

I know about http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0021.html, and according to it extended handshake could be like:

```
{m: {ut_pex=1, ut_metadata=2}, upload_only=1, metadata_size=31236}
```

But I see handshake like

```
{m: {ut_pex=1, ut_metadata=2, upload_only=3}, metadata_size=31236}
```

And even more, I saw handshake like

```
{m: {ut_pex=1, ut_metadata=2, upload_only=3}, upload_only=1, metadata_size=31236}
```

Could somebody explain what does `upload_only=3` mean in extended BitTorrent handshake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `upload_only=3` is within the **m**essage dictionary in the extension handshake.
This means that a extension message with *extension message id=3* is defined as a `upload_only` message.

Unfortunately BEP21 doesn't reflect how *upload_only* is implemented in practise. It should be deprecated and replaced with a better one.

From my answer to another question [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110910/bittorrent-extended-message/44112206#44112206)

> **Addendum:**
>   uTorrent and most other clients implementation of *upload_only* differs from the 'out of date' [specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101150035/http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0021.html) explained [here; <sub>alus = Greg Hazel</sub>](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/45946-clarification-of-partial-seeds/?do=findComment&comment=280236)
>   It's defined as a *extension message* in the *extension handshake* were the 1 byte message data means: **0x00 = false** or **< anything else> = true**. 
>   This can be verified by using Wireshark.